# Unable to launch discord bot due to invalid token

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I am trying to host a discord bot using Heroku, and I have my config variables and everything set up in Heroku. But when I do `client.login(process.env.TOKEN)`, it gives me this error:

```
(node:14392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (C:\Users\hello\Documents\Programming\Discord\Vibes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:205:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hello\Documents\Programming\Discord\Vibes\index.js:14:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1256:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1277:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1105:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've researched online, but I haven't found an answer that helps me.

Comment: did you correctly set the enviroment variable?

Comment: Try to `console.log()` the token to see if it returns what you think it does.

Comment: I mistyped and I meant to type that I set up my config variables in heroku and everything. I don't have a .env file.

Comment: @Lioness100 console.log just returns `[Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_INVALID'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:: [Dot Env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```
require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env.TOKEN)
```

And you can have problem with multi lines string value. it can be a issue, i had this problem with cert keys. Try to check it can correctly read one line value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what is inside the .env file it should be
`TOKEN=""`

If it doesn't work try to replace 'process.env.TOKEN' with the token if it doesn't work too then the token is wrong.

Comment: I mistyped the question, and I meant I set up the config variables in heroku and stuff like that, so I don't have a .env file. Sorry for the confusion